# How to connect Visual Studio 2015 with WAMP Server 3 using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, wamp, wampserver

I am having a hard time trying to connect WAMP with Visual Basic. 
I have been using Access to manage my databases but i seem to run into performance issues in my Server when trying to run the program like freezing. My Professor suggested that I use WAMP instead so I started scratch to see if I can migrate my current program into using WAMP instead of access. Problem is I don't know how to connect to the database.

Running on Visual Studio Community 2015
WAMP Server 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

NVM :)
The internet really lacks a proper guide on how to do it.
Been searching for more than an hour now and finally got it.

Most of the answers are scattered throughout the web.

1. Install the latest MySQL for Visual Studio here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=469618
2. Extract all the folders onto your desktop then select one version which corresponds to your choice
3. Open Visual Studio, open or create your VB Project, go to Project>*PROJECTNAME* Properties>References Then click add.
4. Click Browse and go to folder you just recently extracted the files from and open the version which you have selected
5. Highlight everything inside that folder and click ADD then click CONTINUE
6. Go to your VB Form and view the codes by pressing F7 on your keyboard
7. On top of the Public Class Declaration, type

   `imports mysql.data.myclient`
8. Create a connection string like this:

   `Dim con as New MysqlConnection`
9. Create a declaration for an SQL Command and Reader:

   `dim cmd as new mysqlcommand`and `dim reader as mysqlreader`.
10. Declare the connection string using the ff. format:

    `connection.ConnectionString = String.Format("server=lservername; user=userID; database=dbName")`

    Add `password=pass;` within the string declaration of the connection string

    and then type this to open the Connection:

    `con.Open()`

And that's about it :) ENJOY

Comment: The internet doesn't _"lack a proper guide"_. There are _plenty_ of examples out there that shows how to connect to a database (like you just did) and much more. The very first example I found when googling _"VB.NET connect to MySQL"_ is very similar to yours: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/Tutorials/MsCodes/code8.htm